# Python Pandas merge dataframes without duplicating columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, join, merge

I'm trying to merge two or more dataframes using pandas :

DF1 :

```
   Name     E-mail               Phone Number 
   Trent    trent@example.com    12341234
   Barry    barry@example.com    12345678
   Jared    jared@example.com    56781234
```

DF2 :

```
   Name     E-mail               Age
   Trent    trent@example.com    24
   Barry    barry@example.com    18
   Jared    jared@example.com    31
```

Code :

```
df1 = pd.read_excel("Book1.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel("Book2.xlsx")
files = [df1,df2]

df_all = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left, right, on='Name'), files)
df_all = df_all.drop_duplicates(subset='Name', keep='first')
df_all = df_all.fillna(0)
```

Now the output is :

```
   Name     E-mail_x               Age   E-mail_y             Phone Number
   Trent    trent@example.com      24    trent@example.com    12341234
   Barry    barry@example.com      18    barry@example.com    12345678
   Jared    jared@example.com      31    jared@example.com    56781234
```

is there anyway to remove the "_x" and "_y" and make them just one column

Expected Output :

```
   Name     E-mail                Age      Phone Number
   Trent    trent@example.com      24        12341234
   Barry    barry@example.com      18        12345678
   Jared    jared@example.com      31        56781234
```

**Edit** : The column names [email,age,phone number] are not constant they could change so the names of the columns are in most cases unknown

Comment: `merge(left, right, on=['Name', 'E-mail'],...`?

Comment: Column names are not always known they could change from different dataframes

Comment: If that's the case, then you need to better explain what logic you'd like to use to handle such duplicates. You can either consider a merge that considers all duplicated columns as keys `df1.merge(df2)` or you can trust only the columns from one DataFrame (say the left one) and merge on only name, dropping all other overlapping columns from the right frame. But the result of those two can be vastly different.

Comment: What's wrong with pure `pd.merge(df1, df2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, you do not need the reduce function, you can simply use:

```
df_all = df1.merge(df2)
```

It is duplicating columns because you are merging on 'Name'. If all your columns are the same, you can drop the on='Name' argument and it will merge on all common columns instead of duplicating them.

Alternatively, you can merge only the non-duplicate columns from df2:

```
df_all = df1.merge(df2[['Name','Age']])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using the function `join`:

```py
COMMON_COLUMNS = ["name", "email"]
df3 = df1.join(df2.set_index(COMMON_COLUMNS), on=COMMON_COLUMNS)

df3 = df3.drop_duplicates(subset=COMMON_COLUMNS, keep='first')
```

You can either drop duplicates before the join or after.